# Async function not allowing return type of two promise types in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

node 14.7.0, npm 6.14.7, typescript 3.7.3.

I have a method that queries a postgres database and, depending on a param, will return the first row it finds or the entire result from the query. Similar to this:

```
async getRecord(options: {singleRow: boolean}): Promise<QueryResult> | Promise<Record> {
    const result:QueryResult = await postgres.query(...);
    
    if (options && options.singlerow) {
        return result.rows[0];
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, I receive the following error: `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.` I do not receive an error when I remove the `| Promise<Record>` section, even though the first return (in the if statement) returns a `Promise<Record>`. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try wrapping your return into Promise like `Promise.resolve(result.rows[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `Promise<QueryResult | Record>`

`async` functions need a Promise to box whatever type they return, there's just one top level Promise-type-generic that wraps the return type.